# Redundant Table relationships?

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design

[image]

Is this bad design? SchoolClass has 1 to many relationship to Evaluation
it also has 1 to many relationship to Enroll.

Enroll has 1 to many relationship to ClassScores
and Evaluation has 1 to many relationship to ClassScores.

Entity framework created those tables but it didn't make Evaluation's SchoolClassId as foreign key for SchoolClass that's why I can't make something like evaluation.SchoolClass

Comment: "...but it didn't make Evaluation's SchoolClassId as foreign key for SchoolClass" -- it LOOKS like it did.  You say it didn't?

Comment: yes on EntityFramework it didn't make SchoolClassId as foreign key on Evaluation table. I'm not sure if it because Enroll has already relationship on SchoolClass and both Evaluation and Enroll tables has reference on ClassScores table